# PostgreSql не заполнять таблицу если уже такой id существует

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица:

```
create table users_table
(
    user_id   bigint not null,
    username  varchar(100),
    firstname varchar(100),
    lastname  varchar(100),
    join_date date
);

create unique index users_table_user_id_uindex
    on users_table (user_id);
```

Нужно сделать проверку, если `user_id` существует данные не заполнять. Я пытался сделать сам, но не смог.

Вот ошибка:  `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_table_user_id_uindex"`

Перевод: `повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает уникальное ограничение "users_table_user_id_index"`

Вот метод:

```
void Add_User(long userId, string Username, string Firstname, string Lastname, DateTime joinDate)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command2 = conn.CreateCommand();
            command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users_table VALUES (@userId, @Username, @Firstname, @Lastname, @joinDate)";
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", Firstname);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", Lastname);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@joinDate", joinDate);
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Уникальный индекс уже решает эту задачу. Если значение `user_id` имеется в таблице, вторую запись с тем же значением вставить не получится.

Comment: @Akina, у меня выводит ошибку

Comment: *у меня выводит ошибку* Не, а ты чего хотел? собственно задача решена? решена - запись не появилась в таблице. Всё. Ну а ошибку уж как-нить обработаешь... А если не нравится ошибка, и хочется без неё - ну тогда используй `ON CONFLICT` clause.

Comment: @Akina, благодарю решил `ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO NOTHING`, но теперь другая ошибка `syntax error at or near "$1"` в своем коде я нигде не объявлял `$1`  Указывает на строку `conn.Close();` В методе `Add_User` Что это может быть?

Comment: Задал этот вопрос тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1368922/467311