# Помогите с решением ошибки syntax error at or near "$1" в PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица:

```
create table users_table
(
    user_id   bigint not null,
    username  varchar(100),
    firstname varchar(100),
    lastname  varchar(100),
    join_date date
);

create unique index users_table_user_id_uindex
    on users_table (user_id);
```

Есть код:

```
void Add_User(long userId, string Username, string Firstname, string Lastname, DateTime joinDate)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command2 = conn.CreateCommand();
            command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users_table VALUES (@userId, @Username, @Firstname, @Lastname, @joinDate) ON CONFLICT (@userId) DO NOTHING";
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", Firstname);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", Lastname);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@joinDate", joinDate);
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Есть ошибка:

`syntax error at or near "$1"`      |    POSITION: 66    cs:line 549

`синтаксическая ошибка около или около $ 1` | `ДОЛЖНОСТЬ: 66`

Указывает на метод `Add_User` и строку `command2.ExecuteNonQuery();`
В коде нигде не объявлял `$1`

Comment: `ON CONFLICT (@userId) DO NOTHING` - тут вообще-то должно быть имя поля, а не плейсхолдер для параметра.... собаку - нафиг.

Comment: @Akina, Благодарю!

Comment: "ДОЛЖНОСТЬ: 66" 